# 'Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress' when selecting a value from dropdown, after migrating from v1.2 to v1.6

Tags: angularjs

After migrating our AngularJS application from v1.2.9 to v1.6.9, whenever I click on any dropdown option, I get error in developer console stating

> 'Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress'

I have tried using $timeout solution and it solves the issue for some cases(where $apply was used). However, this specific issue occurs when I am clicking on a dropdown option. I have not called $apply anywhere in my code. I tried using the ng-options in select tag too, however the issue still occurs.

```
Select tag that gives issue:
<select name="task" id="task" ng-model="search.task">
    <option data-ng-repeat="each in taskList" value="{{each.id}}"
            ng-selected="each.id==search.task">
      {{each.taskName}}
    </option>
</select>

Code changes after using ng-options:
<select ng-model="search.task" ng-options="each for each in taskList">
    <option value="">Task Type</option>
</select>
```

[Please follow link for complete error stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rXx1.png)

[image]

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply

How do I fix this error? Any help/pointer is much appreciated.

Comment: Read [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference - Using ngRepeat to generate `select` options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options). Don't use `ng-selected` with `ng-model`.

Comment: @georgeawg : I have tried the above solution, no luck! I am facing this $apply issue for all select boxes across the application.

Comment: Please note I am facing this issue only after the migration to 1.6, everything is working as expected in v1.2.x.

Comment: The stack trace shows the second apply coming from `login_script.js` line 18665.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: $rootScope:inprog — What is the correct way to 'not' execute $apply in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923234/error-rootscopeinprog-what-is-the-correct-way-to-not-execute-apply-in-a)

Answer (score 0):

### Don't use `ngSelected` with `ngModel`<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51014228/5535245)</sup>

```
<select name="task" id="task" ng-model="search.task">
    <option data-ng-repeat="each in taskList" value="{{each.id}}"
            ̶n̶g̶-̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶=̶"̶e̶a̶c̶h̶.̶i̶d̶=̶=̶s̶e̶a̶r̶c̶h̶.̶t̶a̶s̶k̶"̶ >
      {{each.taskName}}
    </option>
</select>
```

From the Docs:

> Note: `ngSelected` does not interact with the `select` and `ngModel` directives, it only sets the `selected` attribute on the element. If you are using `ngModel` on the select, you should not use `ngSelected` on the options, as `ngModel` will set the select value and selected options.
>
> — [AngularJS ng-selected Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected)

See additional Docs:

- [Using `ng-repeat` to generate `select` options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options)
- [Using select with `ng-options` and setting a default value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-select-with-ngoptions-and-setting-a-default-value)

See Stackoverflow:

- [Using `ng-repeat` to generate select options (with Demo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794759/using-ng-repeat-to-generate-select-options/42796398#42796398)

---

### Diagnosing Error: `$rootScope:inprog` Action Already In Progress<sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42925226/5535245)</sup>

When you get this error it can be rather daunting to diagnose the cause of the issue. The best course of action is to investigate the stack trace from the error. You need to look for places where `$apply` or `$digest` have been called and find the context in which this occurred.

There should be two calls:

- The first call is the good `$apply`/`$digest` and would normally be triggered by some event near the top of the call stack.
- The second call is the bad `$apply`/`$digest` and this is the one to investigate.

Once you have identified this call you work your way up the stack to see what the problem is.

If the second call was made in your application code then you should look at why this code has been called from within an `$apply`/`$digest`. It may be a simple oversight or maybe it fits with the sync/async scenario described earlier.

If the second call was made inside an AngularJS directive then it is likely that it matches the second programmatic event trigger scenario described earlier. In this case you may need to look further up the tree to what triggered the event in the first place.

For more information, see [AngularJS Error Reference - $rootScope/inprog -
Diagnosing This Error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog#diagnosing-this-error)

See also,

- [AngularJS Developer Guide (V1.1) Runtime Concepts](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/guide/concepts#runtime)
- [AngularJS $rootScope/Scope API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)